# I can debug but unable to execute my Selenium C# script

Tags: c#, selenium-rc

If i debug my code its running line by line successfully. but when i run without breakpoints it shows the following error and my script failed.

"Failed PaymentGateway  ProjectFunctions    Test method Project_Automation.Functions.PaymentGateway threw exception:  Selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: There was an unexpected Alert! [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0]."

Browser shows no error in UI. but Error console shows "Error: setting a property that has only a getter"

It shows at the end of a single for loop. i am unable to execute rest of the loops

Comment: Can you provide the culprit code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the property evaluation in one of the debugger windows has a side effect. This happens sometimes, try to turn this setting off in VS to eliminate this:

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Enabled property evaluation and other implicit function calls